# Swift Script stuck while executing command (ffmpeg)

Tags: swift, ffmpeg

I'm writing a swift script that uses the bash command ffmpeg. I've been following [this excellent guide](https://rderik.com/blog/using-swift-for-scripting/). Everything works except for when I try to run ffmpeg to convert a video. Normally I can just do `ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4` to convert a video, which works excellent in the terminal. But when I put it in my script I run into trouble.

This is my swift script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift
import Foundation

let ffmpeg = Process()
ffmpeg.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg")
ffmpeg.arguments = ["-i", "input.mov", "output.mp4"]

let pipe = Pipe()
ffmpeg.standardOutput = pipe

do{
  try ffmpeg.run()
  let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
  if let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    print(output)
  }
} catch {
  print("Error")
}
```

However the process just freezes at the following point and i have to ctrl c to exit:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-with-options Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --cc=clang --host-cflags=-fno-stack-check --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --disable-htmlpages --extra-version=with-options --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

What am I doing wrong in my script?

Comment: Maybe check the error pipe too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `-nostdin` option when calling ffmpeg.

```swift
let ffmpeg = Process()
ffmpeg.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg")
ffmpeg.arguments = ["-nostdin", "-i", "input.mov", "output.mp4"]
```

ffmpeg is waiting for stdin as input.
Here are some useful info from the [ffmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options).

> Enable interaction on standard input. On by default unless standard input is used as an input. To explicitly disable interaction you need to specify -nostdin.

Credits to jazzbox on the [Swift Forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/having-some-issues-running-ffmpeg-via-process/20575).